# combining shaders in THREE.JS

Tags: three.js

I'm writting a shader to render terrain from a heightmap and all goes good exept that after I have my shader I loose lights and shades. And here is when hell pain begins. It comes that I should use `THREE.ShaderChunk` to add default shaders chunks but not just add - mess with my shader.

So after long time googling I came to [this advise](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1135)

> You just need to add few snippets to your custom ShaderMaterial at
>   proper places:
>
> // uniforms
>
> THREE.UniformsLib[ "shadowmap" ],
>
> // fragment shader
>
> THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_fragment" ], THREE.ShaderChunk[
>   "shadowmap_fragment" ],
>
> // vertex shader
>
> THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_vertex" ], THREE.ShaderChunk[
>   "shadowmap_vertex" ],

but for me that was not added lights and shadows. Then the best I can thought of is to look at [ShaderLib.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js) and try to use settings from one of default shaders. So I took settings for `lambert` and ended up with this code:

```
        @tileMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial
        uniforms:  THREE.UniformsUtils.merge [
            THREE.UniformsLib[ "common" ],
            THREE.UniformsLib[ "fog" ],
            THREE.UniformsLib[ "lights" ],
            THREE.UniformsLib[ "shadowmap" ],

            {
                "emissive" : { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x000000 ) },
                "wrapRGB"  : { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1 ) }
            }

        ]
        vertexShader: [
            "#define LAMBERT",

            "varying vec3 vLightFront;",

            "#ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED",

            "   varying vec3 vLightBack;",

            "#endif",

            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "common" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_pars_vertex" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lightmap_pars_vertex" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "envmap_pars_vertex" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lights_lambert_pars_vertex" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "color_pars_vertex" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "morphtarget_pars_vertex" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "skinning_pars_vertex" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_vertex" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_pars_vertex" ],

            "void main() {",

                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lightmap_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "color_vertex" ],

                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "morphnormal_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "skinbase_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "skinnormal_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "defaultnormal_vertex" ],

                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "morphtarget_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "skinning_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "default_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_vertex" ],

                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "worldpos_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "envmap_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lights_lambert_vertex" ],
                THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_vertex" ],

            "}"

        ].join "\n"
        fragmentShader: [
            "uniform vec3 diffuse;",
        "uniform vec3 emissive;",
        "uniform float opacity;",

        "varying vec3 vLightFront;",

        "#ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED",

        "   varying vec3 vLightBack;",

        "#endif",

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "common" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "color_pars_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_pars_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "alphamap_pars_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lightmap_pars_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "envmap_pars_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_pars_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "specularmap_pars_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_pars_fragment" ],

        "void main() {",

        "   vec3 outgoingLight = vec3( 0.0 );",
        "   vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );",

            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_fragment" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_fragment" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "color_fragment" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "alphamap_fragment" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "alphatest_fragment" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "specularmap_fragment" ],

        "   #ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED",


        "       if ( gl_FrontFacing )",
        "           outgoingLight += diffuseColor.rgb * vLightFront + emissive;",
        "       else",
        "           outgoingLight += diffuseColor.rgb * vLightBack + emissive;",

        "   #else",

        "       outgoingLight += diffuseColor.rgb * vLightFront + emissive;",

        "   #endif",

            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lightmap_fragment" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "envmap_fragment" ],
            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_fragment" ],

            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "linear_to_gamma_fragment" ],

            THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_fragment" ],

        "   gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, diffuseColor.a );",

        "}"
        ].join "\n"
        attributes:
            height:
                type: "f"
                value: heightData
        wireframe: no
```

which is still do not add lights and shadows and also throws errors:

```
three.js:22804 WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: uniform3fv: no array
three.js:22804 WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: uniform3fv: no array
```

So the question is - what are the steps to add lights and shades to custom shader (as for r71)?

jsfiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/SET001/0wzqemks/2/

Comment: take a look at [THESE](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial) there, maybe they will help

Comment: @2pha, there are just various shader examples but nothing with 'THREE.ShaderChunk' to add existing threejs shaders to custom shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was to add `lights: yes` to `ShaderMaterial`